# Why does converting a Date from a String Object to a Date Object is always nil in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, formatter

I have the following Date string

```
2021-08-06T22:46:31+02:00
```

I am trying to convert it to a `Date` object using the following code but it is always `nil`

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ"
    print(dateFormatter.date(from: date) as Any)
```

In the print statement I get

```
nil
```

Comment: Your date format is wrong. Should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX’. You should also set your locale to en_US_POSIX before setting your  date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `nil` because your format string cannot match the input string.
You need to include the delimiting dashes and colons.

If you fix the format string, then it will work:

```swift
let fm = DateFormatter()
fm.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
fm.date(from: str)
```

Alternatively, as your date is in ISO 8601 format anyway, it's going to be easiest to just use an `ISO8601DateFormatter`.

```swift
let fm = ISO8601DateFormatter()
fm.date(from: str)
```

Comment: So this works but it has a problem the time which is the hours is two hours less

Comment: @Ahmed Because your original string expresses a date in UTC+2 hours, whereas the `description` of a `Date` formats it in your local time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Use this format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`